# Profile implementation in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is my Profile.java file in which i want to add the code for "item 1" that when it was clicked it must associate with my custom.java file.

```
package com.haider.first;

public class Profile
        extends ListActivity
        implements OnItemLongClickListener {

    Activity activity;

    //on create method
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

        //Registering list for context menu
        activity = this;
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        registerForContextMenu(lv);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.profile)));
    }

    //this is code for create context menu
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    // this is code for selecting context item to perform desired actions
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                // Here i need code from which after click custom.java will be selected or choosen
            case R.id.item2:
                startActivity(new Intent(Profile.this, Custom.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    //This is code for Enable Single CLick while opening Context Menu
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        activity.openContextMenu(l);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    //This code disbale long click 
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> enter code here parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        activity.closeContextMenu();
        return false;
    }
}
```

code for custom.java file in which all settings are implemented

```
public class Custom
        extends Activity {

    private SeekBar mediaVlmSeekBar = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;

    //Oncreate Method
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_sett);
        initControls();

        // Code for vibration but my app vibrates after short time intervals even it is closed

        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            //this method is for changing status of mutiple options.
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(isChecked) {
                    Intent vibintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Vibration.class);
                    startService(vibintent);
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        //Code for Controlling Volume, here i am facing issue that i cannot change volume of my app with device buttons
        /Here is my code for Volume

        private void initControls () {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mediaVlmSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            mediaVlmSeekBar.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            //Set the progress with current Media Volume 
            mediaVlmSeekBar.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

            try {
                mediaVlmSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

                    ..........
```

Now my problem is when user will select item 1 named "General" it would select custom.java file without opening. In other words , when user select General the whole settings for volume, vibration, ringtone etc will be automatically selected.

Comment: It helps to understand your own code if you actually indent and format it properly. Just an FYI.

Comment: sorry, i could not understand. I have read my code a number of times but i really do not know how to handle my code now for appropriate result